# XML parsing - date format

Tags: android, xml

How could I format date (remove +0000) that I have pulled with an XML parser?

Here's the code of the date pull:

```
                NodeList dateList = fstElmnt
                    .getElementsByTagName(KEY_DATE);
            Element dateElement = (Element) dateList.item(0);
            dateList = dateElement.getChildNodes();

            Log.d("",
                    "Date = "
                            + ((Node) dateList.item(0))
                                    .getNodeValue());

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
            map.put(KEY_CONTENT,
                    ((Node) contentList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
            map.put(KEY_DATE,
                    ((Node) dateList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            menuItems.add(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

Mybe like this I hope it helps?

```
 Date d = new Date();
 CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yy");
 s.toString
```